# How to publish html pagelayout file?

Tags: page-layout, publishing

How to publish a pagelayout html file? I have a pagelayout which exists about 2 files:

- customPageLayout.html
- customPageLayout.aspx

In the gui it is only possible to publish the html file. The aspx file will be automatically modified and published.

How to publish these 2 files in powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To publish page layout via PowerSell , Try to run the following Script :

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://yoursitecollection

$pages = "http://yoursitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/customPageLayout.html"
,"http://yoursitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/customPageLayout.aspx"

$pages | ForEach-Object { $item = $web.GetListItem($_)
    if ($item.File.CheckOutType -ne "None")
    {
        $item.File.CheckIn("checked in", "CheckIn");
    }
    if ($item.Versions[0].Level -ne "Published")
    {
        $item.File.Publish("published");
    }

}
```

To make sure that it's published successfully , open `http://sitecollection/_layouts/15/DesignPageLayouts.aspx` click on ... check the sub menu , you should get `Unpublish this version`

[image]

Comment: thanks this works. Is this also possible with office dev pnp powershell?

Comment: Hi @Ola, I tried this on SharePoint 2013 on-prem that worked propely for me and and based on your feedback, but it's not work with Office 365 Developer Patterns and Practices because the command is different from on-prem Get-SPWeb = and SP online Get-SPOWeb but I think this link may help you https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Bulk-provision-publishing-a2f5db9a and this https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-PowerShell , I am sorry I don't have SharePoint online now to try it , anyway if the links do not help you, please ask this in new question, and more participants will help you,

Comment: I use SP 2013 on-prem. Office Dev Pnp powershell can be used also for on-prem.

Comment: you are right ,dev Pnp worked for both, but I talk about if this will work for SP online or not  ? and to be honest  I don't try to work with dev Pnp  more, so should you ask  at community if it's possible or not , hope you find the accurate answer , meanwhile, I will try to find answer for this :)

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution to publish the html design files with office dev pnp powershell:

Loop into the folder where the html design files are stored. In my situation it is a subfolder in the masterpage gallery. Filter on design html files. For each html design file check it out. Update it to create the associated aspx file. Check it in as a major version (publish). From this point your pagelayout or masterpage can be used.

```
# Retrieve the folder structure
    $folder = Get-SPOFolderItem $url

    # Loop through the folder (subfolders and files)
    $folder | foreach {

        # Is it a folder, recursive call CheckInItem

            # Retrieve all the field of the file
            Get-SPOProperty -ClientObject $_ -Property ListItemAllFields

            # If it is and HtmlDesign locked file we need to skip it
            if($_.ListItemAllFields.FieldValues.MetaInfo -match "HtmlDesignLockedFile"){

            } else {
                # Check if the file needs to be checked out
                if($_.CheckOutType -eq "None"){
                    Set-SPOFileCheckedOut -Url $_.ServerRelativeUrl
                }

                # update list item to create assocation (aspx) file
                $masterpageGalleryList = Get-SPOList -Identity /_catalogs/masterpage

                if($masterpageGalleryList)
                {
                    Set-SPOListItem -List $masterpageGalleryList -Identity $_.ListItemAllFields.Id -Values @{}
                }

                # Publish the file
                Set-SPOFileCheckedIn -Url $_.ServerRelativeUrl -CheckinType MajorCheckIn

                Execute-SPOQuery


        }
    } > $null
```

Comment: Hi @Ola Great job, and I would like to tell you that this answer should be at this question where you mention you need to use PNP , to be helpful for all http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/196455/how-to-publish-a-html-pagelayout-in-pnp-powershell , meanwhile, at this thread you need to do this via PowerShell and don't mention you need to use PNP and you comment at my answer it's worked , so why you remove set as answer although my answer is correct based on your feedback  :) , I think I tried to help you based on your question,

Comment: ok I will change it and mark your answer as the solution. Thanks for your help.