# How to publish a HTML pagelayout in pnp-Powershell?

Tags: powershell, publishing, pnp

I would like to publish a pagelayout html file with pnp-Powershell. This is a custom html pagelayout which is related to an aspx file. These files are stored in the masterpage gallery.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by my self:

```
# Retrieve the folder structure
    $folder = Get-SPOFolderItem $url

    # Loop through the folder (subfolders and files)
    $folder | foreach {

        # Is it a folder, recursive call CheckInItem

            # Retrieve all the field of the file
            Get-SPOProperty -ClientObject $_ -Property ListItemAllFields

            # If it is and HtmlDesign locked file we need to skip it
            if($_.ListItemAllFields.FieldValues.MetaInfo -match "HtmlDesignLockedFile"){

            } else {
                # Check if the file needs to be checked out
                if($_.CheckOutType -eq "None"){
                    Set-SPOFileCheckedOut -Url $_.ServerRelativeUrl
                }

                # update list item to create assocation (aspx) file
                $masterpageGalleryList = Get-SPOList -Identity /_catalogs/masterpage

                if($masterpageGalleryList)
                {
                    Set-SPOListItem -List $masterpageGalleryList -Identity $_.ListItemAllFields.Id -Values @{}
                }

                # Publish the file
                Set-SPOFileCheckedIn -Url $_.ServerRelativeUrl -CheckinType MajorCheckIn

                Execute-SPOQuery


        }
    } > $null
```